# Java WebService call from ApacheCordova

Tags: web-services, cordova, jakarta-ee, glassfish, visual-studio-cordova

I'm really new to apache cordova, I'm actually using visual studio dev kit for Cordova, I have a Java EE aplication running on glassfish and I have this web service:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService(serviceName = "Eventos")
public class Eventos {
@EJB
private ServiceEventoFacadeLocal ejbRef;

@WebMethod(operationName = "findAll")
public List<ServiceEvento> findAll() {
    return ejbRef.findAll();
}

}
```

And this is the Entity:

```
@Entity
public class ServiceEvento implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
private String nombre;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
private BigInteger precioentrada;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
private BigInteger capacidad;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date inicio;
@Size(max = 300)
private String descripción;
@Size(max = 150)
private String ubicacion;
```

So as it says in the title I'm using apache cordova with visual studio, as far as my understanding goes i need to use JavaScript to call the web service,
but I don't really understand how to call the webservice in JS and after traverse the list and display it
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try the ajax post call with json data type?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to JavaScript, you should spend some time getting familiar with basic concepts like the XMLHttpRequest object which is what is used to call web services. After you have a base understanding, you will want to pick a client side JavaScript framework that makes dealing with both it and creating good UI easier. Ionic is a popular one right now that is worth a look and sits on top of AngularJS which is hugely popular. You may also find Monaca's OnsenUI interesting.

There is an [Ionic and Monaca VS template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/05/18/building-mobile-apps-with-ionic-and-monaca.aspx) you can use to create a project and you can also find video courses at [PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-mobile-apps-ionic-framework-angularjs).

The Tools for Apache Cordova [AngularJS todo app](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-samples/tree/master/todo-angularjs) may also be of interest.

Finally, you may find [BreezeJS](http://www.getbreezenow.com/breezejs) interesting since it has some features designed to integrate with [Hibernate backed POJOs](http://breeze.github.io/doc-java-hib/index.html) and integrates well with Angluar.